# Should I Change Project Target Framework When Server Has .NET 4.5.X runtime Installed

Tags: .net, clr, clr4.0

My understanding is that the the 4.5.X runtime is actually an in-place upgrade to the 4.0 runtime.  So in other words, it replaces 4.0.

But if I have applications on a server that target framework version 4.0, will they start using 4.5 framework features?

And more importantly, would it be considered good practice to upgrade my existing applications to my server runtime?
So going to each class library, MVC app, etc and changing the target framework to the corresponding version.

Is that required or considered best practice?

Comment: No, you cannot "accidentally" use 4.5 features, your program will fail to compile.  There is no compelling reason to change the framework target on your existing projects, unless you have a good reason to take advantage of a specific 4.5 feature.  Just that one project is enough, mixing is not a problem.  Very little reason to target 4.5.1 or 4.5.2, they are just maintenance releases that add very few compelling new features.

Comment: @HansPassant, sorry for my miscommunication.  I did not mean the "new" features of .NET 4.5.  But any bug fixes that were introduced in .NET 4.5, will they automatically take affect without changing the target framework?  That is more of what I was asking.  Also, since .NET 4.0 will not be supported in Jan 2016, would that also mean that projects targeting .NET 4.0 should be updated to target the newer .NET 4.5.X / .NET 4.6?

Comment: Yes.  Nothing to do with the version you target.